# Changing style of UIPickerView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, xcode

How can I change the style of a UIPickerview. I want to change its white background to green color and its black frame to red color.
Anyone please help. I am a beginner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know you can't actually change the frame's color, but you can create an image with a transparent area in the middle and add that on top of the frame like so:

```
[picker addSubview:image];
```

As for the background color, you can create your own custom views for each row by implementing the `UIPickerViewDelegate` method:

```
- (UIView *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView 
                        viewForRow:(NSInteger)row 
                        forComponent:(NSInteger)component
                        reusingView:(UIView *)aView;
```

You could then set the background color of the view you return via

```
[myView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor yellowColor]];
```

However this only affects the rows with data. I don't think you can currently set the background color of the component itself which is a shame.

Answer (score 0):

I personally prefer this:

```
[self.picker setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
self.picker.layer.borderColor = [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;
self.picker.layer.borderWidth = 4;
```